# Count links in Arrays in MongoDB collection

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with objects, which are linking to other objects in the array:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f75bedc5489f86666d305e"),
    "id" : "2",
    "links_to" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "label" : null,
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "label" : null,
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 60,
            "label" : null,
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 23,
            "label" : null,
        }, 
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f75bedc5489f86666d305e"),
    "id" : "3",
    "links_to" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "label" : null,
        },
        {
            "id" : 8,
            "label" : null,
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 23,
            "label" : null,
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "label" : null,
        }, 
},
...
```

Now I would like to write a query, which gives as an output for each `id` the number of links. Eg.:

```
{"id": 1, "numberOfLinks": 21},
{"id": 2, "numberOfLinks": 15},
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to keep the count on the document and update it when you either [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) elements of the array using the [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator. In this way the field is maintained on the document itself:

```js
{
    "links_to": [],
    "linkCount": 0
}
```

When you "push"

```js
db.collecction.update(
    {}, 
    { "$push": { "links_to": newLink }, "$inc": { "linkCount": 1 } }
)
```

And "pull":

```js
db.collecction.update(
    {}, 
    { "$pull": { "links_to": newLink }, "$inc": { "linkCount": -1 } }
)
```

Without doing this, you can use the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator from the aggregation framework in Mondern MongoDB to get the array length:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "numberOfLinks": { "$size": "$link_count" }
    }}
])
```

Or in versions prior to MongoDB 2.6 you can count the array members after [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$link_count" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "numberOfLinks": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

So usually unless you want something specifically "dynamic" then just maintain the count on the document. This avoids the overhead of calculation when you query.

Comment: I don't plan to add a new field to the document. It is just for query purposes. Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: @kcpac The "other idea" is the aggregation framework as shown. Read everything. But I am really recommending that you **do** add the field as it is the better way to do this.

Comment: @NeilLunn Why do you insist on using an additional field? Am I missing something? I found it problematic to have precalculated statistics - they are prone to errors. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The simple answer is that a query runs faster than aggregation, especially when you $unwind.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Ok, that one was clear. I thought I was missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is fairly simple to achieve using aggregation:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$links_to" },
  {$group: { _id: {"lti":"$links_to.id"}, numberOfLinks: {$sum: 1} } },
  {$project: { _id:0, id: "$_id.lti", numberOfLinks: "$numberOfLinks" } }
])
```

produces the desired output, though in reversed order of fields, at least in the shell output:

```
{ "numberOfLinks" : 3, "id" : 3 }
{ "numberOfLinks" : 3, "id" : 2 }
{ "numberOfLinks" : 1, "id" : 5 }
{ "numberOfLinks" : 2, "id" : 4 }
{ "numberOfLinks" : 3, "id" : 1 }
```

If you can live with an output like:

```
{ "_id" : { "linksToId" : 3 }, "numberOfLinks" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "linksToId" : 2 }, "numberOfLinks" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "linksToId" : 5 }, "numberOfLinks" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "linksToId" : 4 }, "numberOfLinks" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "linksToId" : 1 }, "numberOfLinks" : 3 }
```

you can skip the `$project` step of the aggregation pipeline.

This is extremely efficient. I did a test basically doing the same thing over a collection of 5M documents with roughly 17M relations. Takes 18 seconds on a not exactly high performance server.